# Assigning numbers to string in pandas using df.replace()

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to assigns numbers to the 'Sex' feature in a dataframe. My code is as follows:

```
df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].replace('male', 1, inplace = True)
df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].replace('female', 2, inplace = True)
```

However, the code gives as outcome of 'None' in the 'Sex' feature of the dataframe. What could be the problem in this code?

Comment: What you want is `pd.factorize`: `df['Sex'] = df['Sex'].factorize()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using pandas DataFrame `replace` when instead you want pandas `.str.replace`. If I'm not mistaken this should work:

```py
df['sex'] = df['sex'].str.replace('male',1)
df['sex'] = df['sex'].str.replace('female',2)
```